# How to send and receive data between emulators?

Tags: android

I want to send data (text data)  from 1 emulator to other emulator. 1 emulator act as server and other as client. where i can get client &  server side code for this, plz help me .

Comment: what kind of data? how should the data be transferred? this question leaves to many questions open. try to be more precise

Comment: please specify more detail how you want to do?

Comment: I am developing restaurant menu app, in which server app will listen for incoming orders and client app will send order detail to server app. I want to simulate this on emulators running on same PC. I dont know how data will be transmitted between 2 emulators. so plz suggest solution for this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get started, the [dev site](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#connecting) has some guidelines for how to interconnect two emulator devices. I largely suspect that you'll be setting up a small mini server on one of your devices and the client device will be sending POST messages. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/android-http-server/) is a good android server app.

I don't know if you're actually going to be using the emulator or real devices but these two links should help you get started on at least developing the app and testing it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both devices are connected to the same WIFI network, you could use sockets:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html